# Refreshing div or load text without refreshing whole page

Tags: html, text, refresh

I want to reload my text about every 5 seconds, so that my users see that they have new mail... My code looks like this:

```
If C_Mess "0" Then <span class="message-count"> C_Mess </ span> Else 0 End If
```

Can anyone help me to reload this every 5 seconds or something? Javacript / jQuery or whatever.

I want to refresh `<span class="message-count"> C_Mess </ span>`.

Very grateful for answers.

Comment: What server side language is this? C_Mess? Either way, read into AJAX.

Comment: C_Mess=Conn.Execute("Select Count(id) From community_super_mess Where toId=" & Cint(Session("user_id")) & " And reed=0 and mapp=0").Fields(0)

Comment: What do you mean where. Google what AJAX is and learn about it. Then use it to inject code into your div every five seconds or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- For ease i'm just using a JQuery version hosted by JQuery- you can download any   version and link to it locally -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>

    var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
       $('#responsecontainer').fadeOut("slow").load('response.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 5000);

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="responsecontainer">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i found this code en already tryid. i dont want to load a page, i want to load just a code there my messages getting loaded "<% C_Mess %> "

Comment: I tried like this:

<%If C_Mess > "0" Then%><script>
var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
      $(".message-count").hide().html("<%=C_Mess%>").fadeIn('fast');
    }, 5000);
</script>

Dosent work!! :S

Answer (score 0):

I would place the following inside of a `setTimeout` function:

```
$(".message-count").hide().html('the new message count').fadeIn('fast');
```

Comment: (function(){
   $(document).ready(function() {update();});

   function update() { 
      $("#responsecontainer").append(".");
      setTimeout('update()', 5000);     }
 })(); - Something like this?